# How to correctly deploy a Flutter web app using HostGator as a server?

Tags: flutter, deployment, dns, hosting, cpanel

I am attempting to deploy a Flutter web application and have chosen HostGator as my hosting server. Despite following the deployment process I used in the past, the website does not appear online. Below are the steps I've taken, followed by a description of the problem.

**Deployment Steps:**

1. In the terminal, I executed the command to build the Flutter web app for release with the CanvasKit renderer:

   flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release
2. I compressed the build output into a ZIP file and uploaded it to the `public_html` directory within my cPanel's file manager, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Previously, after updating the DNS settings, my website would be live within 3 days. However, this time, even after waiting, the website is not accessible.

**Troubleshooting Attempts:**

- Checked DNS settings to ensure they are correctly pointed to the HostGator servers.
- Verified that the `public_html` directory contains the correct build files from the Flutter project.

Despite these checks, the website remains offline.

**Question:**

What could be causing this deployment issue, and how can I resolve it to successfully deploy my Flutter web app on HostGator?

Thank you for any guidance or insights you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `flutter.js` file. Please check `./your-app/build/web` folder for the missing file(s), or try to run `flutter clean` and then `flutter build web` again.

Answer (score 3):

you need to update your index.html

Change

```
<base href="/">  to <base href="./">
```